# Change minimum password length for customers in SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.8, api, soap, security

**TL;DR:** how do I change the minimum password length requirement for customers created via the SOAP v2 API?

I need to change the minimum password length requirement for customers created via the SOAP V2 API but can't find which file(s) I need to edit. I've tried using grep to check for occurrences of the password length being checked but only found the front-end code for that. It seems like there is some mapping between the SOAP layer and the model layer I'm not aware of, any pointers would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: So I realised that I was using grep with the case sensitive mode, which was excluding everything, since all the soap files are named `Soap.php`. Still looking, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Customer creation**

I assume you're using the standard [customerCustomerCreate](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.create.html)() SOAP v2 Method.

This method is referenced in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/wsdl.xml` (grep for: "customerCustomerCreate").
The method `create` is defined in `Model/Customer/Api.php` where you can see that the `customer/customer` Model is called:

```
class Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Api extends Mage_Customer_Model_Api_Resource
{
 ....
/**
 * Create new customer
 *
 * @param array $customerData
 * @return int
 */
public function create($customerData)
{
    $customerData = $this->_prepareData($customerData);
    try {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setData($customerData)
            ->save();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $customer->getId();
}
... 
}
```

The `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Api_V2` class extends `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Api`.
So you'll need a bit of effort just to change it for the created customers via SOAP.

The **password** length is hardcoded in `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Attribute_Backend_Password` (see: `$len = Mage::helper('core/string')->strlen($password);` and `if ($len < 6)` ).

Comment: As a note to any travellers showing up from google, we also needed to modify the frontend-code so that it matched the changes made where you suggested. Thanks!